# Jar file and artefactId (Maven) naming conventions

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have a package

> com.my.domain.subdomain

Would it be okay to name **artefactId** (maven) after

> com.my.domain.subdomain

And then **groupId**

> com.my.domain

And then final artifact (jar file)

> com.my.domain.subdomain-0.0.2.jar

What I want to know is would I break any rules of naming and if it is acceptable
or it is a no go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no plans to publish those artifacts to the public repositories, then you may choose whatever fits.

But - never say never!

If, on the other hand, there is a possibility to publish artifacts one day, you should follow the requirements of the target repository, for example [Choose your coordinates](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/coordinates/) if you want to publish to the Maven Central.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, I was reading this article
https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/tutorials/java-modularity-4/, which gives an impression that naming jar's after modules is ok (even if I want to push it to maven central repository). Can you confirm it or deny it?

Comment: The article you've referenced does not speak about Maven at all. The concept of Group ID is **absent** both from the JPMS and from the IntelliJ IDEA. I would recommend to avoid using dots (.) in the artifact ID for the following reasons: 1. Confusion between Group ID and ArtifactID. --- 2. Windows and MacOS X do strange things to filenames which contain dots.